# Wacom Intuos with touch scrolling not working in PhpStorm

Tags: macos, scrolling, phpstorm

I work with my mac in a doc so the touchpad isn't used most of the time so I use a mouse or my Intuos Pen & Touch pad.

Scrolling works normally in almost all applications except PhpStorm which is where I spend the bulk of my work day.

When I attempt to scroll the scrollbar is jumping like it can't figure out if it's supposed to go up or down.

I've tried turning on/off "natural" scrolling in both the Wacom and Mac Trackpad settings to no avail.

Here's a link to the screen capture I took of the issue on YouTube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWBqQoWlTHU

Anyone else have this issue and able to resolve?

I'm also reaching out to IntelliJ for help since the platform is known to be a little buggy with scrolling since Mac Sierra came out. But I figured if someone here has experienced this issue and solved it, I might be able to get help faster ;)

Edit: Link to the issue I submitted to IntelliJ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34365

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in the latest Wacom Intuos driver version 6.3.19 (big surprise, right?).

Try the previous version: http://cdn.wacom.com/u/productsupport/drivers/mac/professional/WacomTablet_6.3.18-4.dmg

Scrolling works for me on 6.3.18, but right-click doesn't (on Sierra & my Intuos5 Touch).

Someone else recommended http://cdn.wacom.com/u/productsupport/drivers/mac/professional/WacomTablet_6.3.15-3.dmg, but I haven't tried to downgrade that far back, yet.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Here's hoping!

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest Wacom tablet as well as the most recent version of Photoshop (at the time of writing this its Adobe Photoshop CC 2017.0.1).  To get the Wacom Tablet to work with zoom I had to edit the Photoshop preferences:

[image]

Make sure "Zoom with scroll wheel" is selected!

That was my issue.